# Access QT Designer Objects Programmatically

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Disclaimer: New to both python and qt designer

QT Designer 4.8.7

Python 3.4

PyCharm 5.0.3

Question - How do I add controls to the main form or a scroll area widget on the main form (created in QT Designer) programmatically?

I have created a MainWindow in qt designer and added my widgets. The following is the entire test program in PyCharm:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore,  uic

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from PyQt4.QtCore import *

qtCreatorFile = "programLauncher.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

    # Cannot resize or maximize
    self.setFixedSize(1045, 770)

    # Add button test
    self.dateLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Test")
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Test button')

    # self.scrollArea_programs.addWidget()

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    # self.scrollArea_programs.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    grid.addWidget(self.dateLabel,0,0)
    grid.addWidget(self.pushButton,0,1)
    self.setLayout(grid)

    self.pushButton_exit.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

def closeEvent(self):
    QtGui.QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyApp()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see I tried to add controls to a grid but nothing shows up when the program runs - I have also tried to add a control to the scroll area. Can someone help me to just add 1 control to the scroll area at run time - so then I can know the proper way to do it or "a" proper way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having access to your `programLauncher.ui` and making minimal changes to your posted code, you can add your UI elements to the window like so:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Cannot resize or maximize
        self.setFixedSize(1045, 770)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        # Add button test
        self.dateLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Test")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Test button')

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.dateLabel, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1)
        widget.setLayout(grid)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will get the controls on the screen, although the layout leaves a lot to be desired. You may have to make modifications to this based on what's in your `.ui` file. One thing that you'll want to note in this example is that the `QMainWindow` needs a central widget (`widget` in the example above). You then set the layout on that widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the designer to create your `.ui` file
The you can load it in your `.py` using something like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
class my_win(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('my_ui.ui',self)
```

then you can access all your widgets with something like

```
self.ui.actionQuit.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
```

or

```
self.ui.my_button.triggered.connect(self.do_someting)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JCVanHamme (the programLauncher.ui hint) and also outside help I now learned most of what I need to know to access MainWindow at run time. So for anyone interested in this beginner tip:

1. Take a blank form in QT Designer
2. Add a control
3. Run pyuic4 batch file
4. Take a look at the generated .py file to learn EVERYTHING about how to add controls.

Don't let the power go to your head - cheers